# How is Subgaussian inequality getting satisfied?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

> I am trying to understand the assumption proof of Theorem 2 in the paper ["A Universal Law of Robustness via isoperimetry"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.12806.pdf) by Bubeck and Sellke.

---

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sqrt{\frac{d}{c n L^{2}}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}[f]\right) z_{i} \geq t\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-(t / 9)^{2}\right) ............(1)
$$
We rewrite the above as:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}[f]\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2}}\right).....................(2)
$$
Since we assumed that the range of the functions is in $[-1,1]$ we have $\mathbb{E}[f] \in[-1,1]$ and hence:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[f] z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right).............(3)
$$

---

1.How Equation 2 is coming from Equation 1? How  can it be  rewritten like this?

2. How Equation 3 is forming?

Update :
[Can anybody help me in this follow up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471556/how-can-i-perform-union-operation-into-two-events)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the jump from equation 1 to 2 you can follow this procedure
\begin{align}
    2\exp(-(t/9)^2) 
    &\geq \mathbb{P}\left (\sqrt{\frac{d}{cnL^2}}\sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - \mathbb{E}[f])z_i \geq t \right ) & (\text{Eq. 1})\\
    =& \mathbb{P}\left (\sqrt{\frac{cL^2}{dn}} \sqrt{\frac{d}{cnL^2}}\sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - \mathbb{E}[f])z_i \geq \sqrt{\frac{cL^2}{dn}}t \right ) \\
    =& \mathbb{P}\left (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - \mathbb{E}[f])z_i \geq \sqrt{\frac{cL^2}{dn}}t \right )
\end{align}
where the second line is just multiplying both sides of the inequality by the same positive constant, and the third is just simplifying.

Now choose $t = \sqrt{\frac{dn}{cL^2}}\frac{\epsilon}{8}$. Plugging this into the first and last gives
\begin{align} 
\mathbb{P}\left (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - \mathbb{E}[f])z_i \geq \sqrt{\frac{cL^2}{dn}} \sqrt{\frac{dn}{cL^2}}\frac{\epsilon}{8} \right ) &\leq 2\exp\left (-\left (\frac{1}{9} \sqrt{\frac{dn}{cL^2}}\frac{\epsilon}{8}\right )^2 \right ) \\
\mathbb{P}\left (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i) - \mathbb{E}[f])z_i \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8} \right ) & \leq 2\exp\left (-\left (\frac{1}{9} \sqrt{\frac{dn}{cL^2}}\frac{\epsilon}{8}\right )^2 \right ) \\
&=2\exp\left(-\frac{1}{9^2}\frac{\epsilon^2}{8^2}\frac{dn}{cL^2}\right) \\
&\leq 2\exp\left (-\frac{\epsilon^2nd}{9^4cL^2} \right)
\end{align}
which proves the first part.

For the second part of the question, we need the basic fact that if "not $B$" implies "not $A$," then $\mathbb{P}(A) \leq \mathbb{P}(B)$. To see this, note that
\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(A) &= \mathbb{P}(A \text{ and } B) + \mathbb{P}(A \text{ and not } B) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(A|B)\mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{P}(A|\text{not } B)\mathbb{P}(\text{not } B) \\
&\leq 1\mathbb{P}(B) + 0\mathbb{P}(\text{not } B) = \mathbb{P(B)}
\end{align}
With this in mind, let $B$ be the event $\left| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right | \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}$ and let $A$ be the event
$$\exists f \in \mathcal{F} \text{ s.t. } \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[f]z_i \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}.$$
Now note that since $|\mathbb{E}[f]| \in [0,1]$, we have if not $B$ then
\begin{equation}
\frac{\epsilon}{8} > \left| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right | \geq |\mathbb{E}[f]|\left| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n z_i \right | \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[f]z_i 
\end{equation}
which mean not $B$ implies not $A$, and we can apply the bound above.

Comment: Thanks! for such elaborated explanation. Can you just tell me , Why you have written P(A given B) as 1 in the proof of second part!

Comment: It should be ---- "if "not A" implies "not B," then P(A)≤P(B)".

Comment: Yes there was backwards inequality in the sentence, I corrected it to "if not B implies not A, then P(A) <= P(B)". The reason I exchanged P(A|B) for 1 because 1 is always an upper bound on a probability, and therefore P(A|B)P(B) <= P(B). This can also be seen by spotting P(A and B) <= P(B).

Comment: okay. Yes , P(A and B) <= P(B) by same logic P(A and not B) <= P(not B), why 0 * P(not B).Am I missing something? :(  Not B implies Not A,; in the second term there is P(A given not B) , hence is it 0??

Comment: The reason it's 0 is because we are assuming that "not B" implies "not A" and therefore P(not A | not B) = 1. By the sum rule P(A | not B) + P(not A | not B) = 1, and therefore P(A | not B) + 1 = 1 which implies P(A | not B) = 0.

Comment: @M.Werenki Can you help me in this, I am really struggling https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471556/how-can-i-perform-union-operation-into-two-events

Answer (score 0):

1. Set
   $$\epsilon = 9t \sqrt{\frac{cL^2}{dn}}$$
2. If $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n E[f] z_i \ge \epsilon / 8$, then
   $$E[f] \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n z_i\right) > 0$$
   which implies
   $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n E[f] z_i = \left|E[f]\right| \left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n z_i\right|
   \le \left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n z_i\right|.$$